# No material widget found textfield widgets require a material widget ancestor

Tags: android, ios, material-design, flutter

Hi I am trying to build a login screen in flutter but I am getting below error when opening it.

> No material widget found textfield widgets require a material widget ancestor

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 Widget LoginPage() {
    return new Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        image: DecorationImage(
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05), BlendMode.dstATop),
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/mountains.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(120.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.headset_mic,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "EMAIL",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'samarthagarwal@live.com',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "PASSWORD",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: '*********',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    "Forgot Password?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new FlatButton(
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 20.0,
                        horizontal: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "LOGIN",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 0.25)),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "OR CONNECT WITH",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 0.25)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: new FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0Xff3B5998),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            child: new Container(
                              child: new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Expanded(
                                    child: new FlatButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 20.0,
                                        bottom: 20.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: new Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            const IconData(0xea90,
                                                fontFamily: 'icomoon'),
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 15.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "FACEBOOK",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: new FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0Xffdb3236),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            child: new Container(
                              child: new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Expanded(
                                    child: new FlatButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 20.0,
                                        bottom: 20.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: new Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            const IconData(0xea88,
                                                fontFamily: 'icomoon'),
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 15.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "GOOGLE",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Error states that **TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.** Simply **wrapping** your whole loginWidget into `Scaffold` will solve the problem.

```
Widget LoginPage() {
   return new Scaffold(body: *your whole code*)
}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative if I don't want to use `Scaffold`.

Comment: You could wrap it with `Material`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28326#issuecomment-466404656

Answer (score 40):

Just wrap your widget with Material like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    child: YourAwesomeWidget(),
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Since most of the widget asks for material widget as their parent widget

its a good practice you should use `Material()` or `Scaffold()` widget on **top of the widget tree** and then continue your code.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    child: body(),
}
```

OR

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    child: body(),
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Wrap the loginpage function with a Scaffold or a MaterialApp

```
Widget LoginPage() {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      *the rest of your code*
    ),
  );
}
```

or

```
Widget LoginPage() {
  return new MaterialApp(
    home: Container(
      *the rest of your code*
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I encountered your same problem. Always remember to enter Scaffold remembering that it must be included as a parent who creates the page, inside it after, you will insert all the widgets you want, but Scaffold after MaterialApp is the second component that must be added if you are creating a new page.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to show a `TextFormField` as my `content` widget in a `CupertinoDialogAlert`.  My fix was to wrap content in a `Card` with an elevation of 0 and transparent color.  `content` is an argument passed as a Widget. So it could really be any type of widget.  I noticed that if I pass a Text widget, it loses its centering, so I programmatically do that as well.

```
      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: title,
          content: Card(
              elevation: 0,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: (content is Text)
                  ? Text(content.toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                  : content,
          actions: actions);
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. 
Although I had to use the Theme widget and set the brightness to light. For some reason it was too dim.