# textfield keep messing around

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. I want to achieve like this.
[image]
but my visual studio code keep saying an error[image]

Comment: Please provide your code in text format.

Comment: Please refer this link might be helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947552/no-material-widget-found ans also this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772910/no-material-widget-found-textfield-widgets-require-a-material-widget-ancestor

Answer (score 1):

Change Theme According to your requirements

```
Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Login Screen App"),
              ),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Code Playon"),
                  
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "User Name"
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, refer [**`TextFormField`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Login Screen App"),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'CodeplayOn',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'User Name.',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Result screen->  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a
`MaterialApp` widget
at the root of your widget's tree, and a
`Scaffold` widget
encapsulating your `Search` widget and you should be good to go!